# How to use if statements with in_array()?

Tags: php, html

I´m trying to check wether departure country OR arrival country are inside the EU. 
This is my code:

```
$CountrysEU = array('Austria', 'Belgium', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia', 'Cyprus', 'Czech Republic', 'Denmark', 'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Malta', 'Netherlands', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 'United Kingdom');
$DepartureCountry = 'Croatia';
$ArrivalCountry = 'Belgium';

if(in_array($DepartureCountry, $CountrysEU) || in_array($ArrivalCountry, $CountrysEU)){
    echo 'EU';
}
else {
    echo 'NotEU';
}
```

> It echo "NotEU", what can´t be true as `$ArrivalCountry` is `'Belgium'`.

Does anyone know if `in_array` can work this way and if yes, how to fix that code ?

I don´t understand why this code doesn´t work, the code works if I remove the second part with `||` like this:

```
$CountrysEU = array('Austria', 'Belgium', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia', 'Cyprus', 'Czech Republic', 'Denmark', 'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Malta', 'Netherlands', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 'United Kingdom');
$DepartureCountry = 'Croatia';
$ArrivalCountry = 'Belgium';

        if(in_array($DepartureCountry, $CountrysEU)){
            echo 'EU';
        }
        else {
            echo 'NotEU';
        }
```

My third try:

```
$CountrysEU = array('Austria', 'Belgium', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia', 'Cyprus', 'Czech Republic', 'Denmark', 'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Malta', 'Netherlands', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 'United Kingdom');
$DepartureCountry = 'Croatia';
$ArrivalCountry = 'Belgium';

        if(in_array($DepartureCountry, $CountrysEU || in_array($ArrivalCountry, $CountrysEU)){
            echo 'EU';
        }
        else {
            echo 'NotEU';
        }
```

> It echo: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sofort-Flug-Entschädigung\CCPSeven.php on line 137"

**Edit:** 
The Variables `$DepartureCountry` and `$ArrivalCountry` are scraped from a page, if I define them with simple strings the first code works, but that makes no sense to me as the scraped variables work if I remove the `||` Part.

Comment: works for me, https://3v4l.org/qsfnY

Comment: Since you don't have a problem for us, I'm voting to close this question. If you have cookies, I'll take one, yeah.

Comment: `The Variables $DepartureCountry and $ArrivalCountry are scraped from a page` - `var_dump($DepartureCountry, $ArrivalCountry);`, let see what you have

Comment: the problem was in the var, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m answering my own question.

The code works fine, the problem was that the scraped variable had a `" "` in it, that´s why it outputed `NoEU`.

Example: `var = "Belgium"`, not `var = " Belgium"`.

**So before posting any question, check your variables...**

Answer (score 0):

The last example had a missing closing `)` from `in_array` - the following works as expected though having corrected that missing `)`

```
<?php

    $countries = array(
        'Austria',
        'Belgium',
        'Bulgaria',
        'Croatia',
        'Cyprus',
        'Czech Republic',
        'Denmark',
        'Estonia',
        'Finland',
        'France',
        'Germany',
        'Greece',
        'Hungary',
        'Ireland',
        'Italy',
        'Latvia',
        'Lithuania',
        'Luxembourg',
        'Malta',
        'Netherlands',
        'Poland',
        'Portugal',
        'Romania',
        'Slovakia',
        'Slovenia',
        'Spain',
        'Sweden',
        'United Kingdom'
    );

    $depart = 'Croatia';
    $arrive = 'Belgium';

    if( in_array( $depart, $countries ) || in_array( $arrive, $countries ) ){
        echo 'EU';
    } else {
        echo 'NotEU';
    }
?>
```

output

```
EU
```

Comment: `if(in_array($DepartureCountry, $CountrysEU || ` <--- missing `)`

Comment: yea, that one was missing

Comment: but that wasn´t the problem

Comment: ok - I just noticed the comment about these variables being `scraped` but you did not include that scape code - perhaps the problem lies there if statically declared variables work fine

Comment: the problem was in the var, thx